# Android in-app-billing. When to unregister the ResponseHandler?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

We implemented In-app Billing one year ago with no problems following the sample code from the documentation. Some weeks ago we noticed users complaints about not getting their items. While debugging the code we found that the following sentence was the root of the problem:

```
/**
 * Called when this activity is no longer visible.
 */
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ResponseHandler.unregister(mDungeonsPurchaseObserver);
}
```

On my Samsung Galaxy S device this method is being called when the Market screen appears, clearing the observer and interrupting the overall circuit. We've moved the call to the `OnDestroy` method instead and it's working ok now.

Is this the correct way to handle the problem? Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Yes. Unregister in onDestroy and added a 'else' in ResponseHandler.purchaseResponse method:

if (sPurchaseObserver != null) 
    sPurchaseObserver.postPurchaseStateChange...
else 
    //add the purchase details to a SharedPreference and process it later (e.g. onStart of your main activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem. I've implemented a queue on ResponseHandler: if the observer is null, I put the information on the queue; as soon an observer is added, I call it using the information from the queue. It makes sense in my application and it seems to be working fine.

I do not know if putting in onDestroy is a good idea, because it makes no sense to update the interface of an Activity that is not visible.

Are you experiencing any problem with your solution?

Comment: Indeed your solution sounds better. We've a lot of Activities and we're loosing some transactions.
So you're filling the queue in the `else` of the `ResponseHandler.purchaseResponse` method?

Comment: Yes. (`if (sPurchaseObserver == null)`). And then use the queue when register the observer.